# Python package: how to selectively limit visibility of exported modules and packages

Tags: python, module, package

I am trying to build a python package. After reading documentation and other tutorials about modules and packages, I am still a bit confused about how limit the modules/packages exposed on the public interface of the root package (meaning the stuff that the user can import and use with the package).

For example, I have a sample project structured like the following:

```
├── README.md
├── main_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── sub_package_1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── sub1.py
│   └── sub_package_2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── sub2.py
├── package.json
└── setup.py
```

`main_package/main.py`

```py
from .config import Config
from .sub_package_1 import sub1_func
from .sub_package_2 import sub2_func

def main_func():
    print(Config.DUMMY, sub1_func(), sub2_func())
```

`main_package/__init__.py`

```py
from .main import main_func
```

`main_package/sub_package_1/sub1.py`

```py
def sub1_func():
    return 'sub1_func'
```

`main_package/sub_package_1/__init__.py`

```py
from .sub1 import sub1_func
```

`main_package/sub_package_2/sub2.py`

```py
def sub2_func():
    return 'sub2_func'
```

`main_package/sub_package_2/__init__.py`

```py
from .sub2 import sub2_func
```

What I would like to know if there is a way to selectively control what will be exported (visible) on the public interface of the main package. Let's say for this example I want to export only `main_func` from `main_package.main` and the subpackage `sub_package_1` and anything else. Can I do that?

```py
from main_package import main_func  # OK
from main_package import config  # NO!
from main_package.sub_package_1 import sub1_func  # OK
from main_package.sub_package_2 import sub2_func  # NO!
```

It seems I am unable to do so. Every time I build the package, I can import both the sub packages and also the `config.py` module which I don't want at all.

Comment: Interesting question, I think I briefly looked at a similar thing for private state variables but I think my conclusion then was that Python has no notion of private members of any sort, even though you can indicate what shouldn't be called with documentation. I think quite a few SO threads see people importing a library's internal helper function, so I think the "dangerous" scenario you're trying to avoid can't be helped much

Comment: You can define list/tuple `__all__`  only what is listed there can be imported

Comment: @SedyVlk I am afraid that will only impact what you can import with `from <module> import *` statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Comment: There is no privacy in Python. So the answer is you can't. But you can prefix with an underscore every name for internal use. So at least the user knows these were not meant for import.